# Ubuntu 20.04 wakes up to pixelated static screen

Tags: 20.04, graphics, display, suspend

**Issue:**
When I wake up my computer after suspending it, I can only see a [pixelated static screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BB5i.jpg). I cannot go further from this screen, so I always end up rebooting the computer. This issue only happens after sleep, never after reboot or when turning on the computer.

**System:**
Model: ThinkPad E14 Gen 2 (14”) AMD Laptop
Processor: AMD® Ryzen 5 4500u with radeon graphics × 6
Graphics: AMD® Renoir
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

**Extra info:**
I have tried updating the system again and reinstalling the drivers, but this didn't solve the problem.

**Extra info 2 (edit):**
When connected to a monitor, the monitor does show the normal screen, but the laptop screen is still pixelated.

Comment: Are you sure your RAM is working?

Comment: As far as I can see it is working, at least before suspension

Comment: I seem to have the same with a 4750U.  Happens on suspend/resume, or if I turn the display on/off when connected to an external monitor.  I updated system firmware to 1.35 just before this started happening, though that revision dates from 2021-07-13.  I boot into a live 20.4.3 and it doesn't happen.  Reverting system firmware didn't help.  Only happens on internal screen, not external monitor.

Comment: Anyone still having this issue can look at more options: [Fuzzy static Noise Screen after awakening from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383378/fuzzy-static-noise-screen-after-awakening-from-suspend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just started having the same problem with my Acer Swift 3 (AMD Ryzen 7 4700U with Radeon graphics) on Ubuntu 20.04.3.

My kernel was a 5.13 version. When I chose a 5.11 kernel in Grub I didn't see the issue reappear. And today I updated to version 5.15.16 and I haven't seen it reoccur since. The release notes mention updates for AMD GPUs, so hopefully that's the fix for our problem.

(There are different ways to do the kernel update, but I just downloaded the 3 appropriate deb files for my system, ran `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`, and disabled secure boot on my machine)

Comment: Thanks! I tried upgrading the kernel to the 5.15.16 version and it solved the issue

Comment: Great, thanks for the update, glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue recently and confirm that up-/down-grading the Linux kernel, as previousuly mentioned by billy helps.

I've tried with 5.11.* Kernel and now running on [5.15.16](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.15.16), since most recent 5.* version.
However, I've purged Nvidia 470* proprietary drivers to get image on external monitors.

Here are more details to my machine:

```
Kernel: Linux 5.15.16-051516-generic #202201200437 SMP Thu Jan 20 10:00:11 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu Version: 20.04.3 LTS
Nvidia driver: X.OrgX Server (open Source)
Processor: AMD® Ryzen 7 4800h with radeon graphics × 16 (Renoir)
Graphics card: Nvidia TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060], driver=nouveau
```

```
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.15.16/amd64/linux-headers-5.15.16-051516_5.15.16-051516.202201200437_all.deb
```

Files I've used for kernel upgrade:

```
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.15.16/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.15.16-051516-generic_5.15.16-051516.202201200437_amd64.deb

wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.15.16/amd64/linux-modules-5.15.16-051516-generic_5.15.16-051516.202201200437_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried upgrading the kernel to the 5.15.16 version and it solved the issue