# Fuzzy static Noise Screen after awakening from suspend

Tags: 20.04, screen

Since one of the recent Ubuntu updates in December 2021, when I awake my laptop by opening the lid OR when I disconnect it from an external monitor, the screen is showing static noise and must be restarted to resolve the issue.
Is anyone else seeing this issue. System info is below.

System info here:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Fuzzy screen here:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Seems like more of us are seeing it (https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1958591), and there are suggestions it was down to the upgrade from kernel 5.11 to 5.13 which just came through.  But you saw it much before.  Are you configured to get -proposed kernel updates by any chance?  Do you know what kernel saw the problem?  If it wasn't 5.13 then that theory gets blown out of the water.

Comment: Reported here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1923

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading the kernel to `5.13.0-28-generic` fixed the issue. Run the following commands to install kernel 5.13:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: actually it was an automatic one for me

Comment: it didn't work for me

Comment: Yep, this kernal update fixed it for me also

Comment: For those whose update failed to fix their state i recommend rollback to the previous kernel 5.11.xx(generic) using grub customization and you can make it default from there too
https://vitux.com/how-to-install-grub-customizer-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem. (roughly same specification as yours).

I finally got mine fixed.

**A warning to anyone reading this**. There is a high probability there is a newer kernel that is compatible with the drivers. This is a functional fix and probably not a perfect one. Anyone with more intimate knowledge of kernel + amdgpu is welcome to contribute a better answer.

You need to download, extract and install the 20.50 amdgpu driver.

This is the link I used:

```
https://drivers.amd.com/drivers/linux/amdgpu-pro-20.50-1234664-ubuntu-20.04.tar.xz
```

extract and run:

```
tar -xf amdgpu-pro-20.50-1234664-ubuntu-20.04.tar.xz
cd amdgpu-pro-20.50-1234664-ubuntu-20.04
./amdgpu-install
```

Then you need to deploy a specific kernel: (`5.4.0-96-generic` is working for me)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-5.4.0-96-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-96-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-96-generic linux-headers-5.4.0-96-generic
```

My laptop also has an nvidia GPU. Install these if needed:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.4.0-96-generic linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.4.0-96-generic linux-signatures-nvidia-5.4.0-96-generic
```

then reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

after reboot, confirm that kernel version was loaded

```
uname -r
```

I changed my grub to allow selecting the kernel at boot time. If `uname -r` returns wrong kernel version, you may need to do the same or change your config to use this specific kernel.  I'm not going to include grub config instructions here, but its a simple modification to `/etc/default/grub`

For reference - this fix is based off information found here: https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-45

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is indeed not a full answer, but since you are trying to help OP, I will not flag it, because it is also kinda written as an answer

Comment: My system was on 5.13 when it started crashing

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04, Lenovo with AMD hardware (CPU and GPU), and started to happen since a recent (automatic) update in ~December 2021.

For me it was [this reported bug #1942419 in ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1942419) regarding missing `renoir_ta.bin` file (different bug as the ones mentioned by other users). It is probably fixed in a future upgrade, but that may take a while to reach you, so here is the fix that worked for me:

- Search the kernel logs for an amdgpu log describing the error, I got:

```bsh
$ cat /var/log/kern* | grep 'amdgpu'

Dec 28 21:17:34 XXXXX kernel: [XXXXX] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: Direct firmware load for amdgpu/renoir_ta.bin failed with error -2
```

- AFAIK, error -2 is file missing
- Download missing file(s) from github: https://github.com/endlessm/linux-firmware/tree/master/amdgpu
- Move missing file(s) to folder `/lib/firmware/amdgpu/`
- Restart the computer