# No option anywhere to add a second monitor

Tags: 20.04, windows, multiple-monitors

FIXED: Solution in comments

[For some reason my version of ubuntu has no second monitor option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFysT.png)
I've looked around and everywhere online they just say either disconnect, reconnect, restart etc and it should work but my options never seem to change and I have no idea why. the menus I see also dont look like my one.

Edit:

- Model: HP omen 15
- Memory: 16GB
- Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 4800h with radeon graphics x16
- Graphics card: GeForce RTX 2060
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Second monitor is a BenQ monitor connected through hdmi and its 1920x1080

It's dual booted with windows. and Windows picks it up fine.

Comment: Indeed there's no "manual" option to add a monitor. It's either detected or it isn't, end of story. Now please edit the question and post your hardware specifications, the monitor you're trying to use, how is it connected and your Ubuntu release/version.

Comment: This fixed it for me https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383378/fuzzy-static-noise-screen-after-awakening-from-suspend
While trying to fix a secondary graphical issue it fixed the first. To be specific I ran the commands and they caused a red warning to appear on my top toolbar on the right and clicking on it and letting it reinstall and restart fixed both issues